# Get SPListItem from an Attachments url?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I`m trying to get the SPListItem from an Attachments url.
What I´m currently trying:

```
string url = "Lists/Tasks/Attachments/27/unnamed.png";
SPListItem i = new SPSite(url).OpenWeb().GetFile(url).Item;
```

But the Property "Item" of the SPFile gotten by "GetFile(url)" is null, so that does not wok.
The "Item" property seems only to work for SPFiles in Document-Libraries...
Has someone another approach?

Thanks!

Comment: An attachment is not a list item. I'm not sure what what need to achieve but did you check the property [SPListItem.Attachments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.attachments.aspx)?

Comment: take alook at here http://www.thesharepointblog.net/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=815f255a-d0ef-4258-be2a-28487dc9975c&ID=61

Comment: I think you both misunderstood my question. Your links are helpful, but don´t show me a way to do it. But thanks anyway!

Comment: @VanCoding How about making your question clearer so we can understand it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my memory serves me right attachments are stored in folder /ListName/Attachments/ItemID/attachment. So you have item id in this url, and can use it to retreive item you want with list.GetItemById method.

Comment: Yes, you´re right, the item ID is in the URL of the file, but I tought that there should be a more elegant way...

Comment: I think that it's the best way, because only alternative i see is to iterate over items in the list and check its attachments. I tried to find a better solution, but finished with this one.

Answer (score -2):

unfortunately attachments are not so much supported in object model. i think the only way is parsing the url and getting the item id. there is no object such as SPAttachment, only SPAttachmentCollection but it is not much than a string collection.

```
SPFile.Item
```

only works for document in a document library, otherwise it is null.